# Django aggregate function returns incorrect value

Tags: python, mysql, django, kvm

This is a very weird error that sometimes happens in our production environment. I use a very simple aggregate (MAX) query to determine the maximum value of a given column in a table:

`last_uid = SomeEntity.objects.all().aggregate(Max('uid_mail'))['uid_mail__max'] or 0`

The issue is that in very rare cases the value returned by this query is incorrect. It has happened maybe 3 or 4 times in 3 years, always with quite disastrous consequences (for instance, yesterday it returned 22 instead of 1722, causing our hosting provider to suspend our site because this error caused a very large amount of mails being sent).

The SQL query issued is straightforward:
DEBUG util (0.002) SELECT MAX(finanzas_enviosiirecibido.uid_mail) AS uid_mail__max FROM finanzas_enviosiirecibido; args=()

I am absolutely certain the returned value was incorrect: we log the value we obtain from this query, and these are the values we got:

On 2014-06-13 03:34:06:

DEBUG siidte lastUid: 1721

On 2014-06-14 05:39:29 (the next day):

DEBUG siidte lastUid: 22

And I am also absolutely certain the rows with values > 22 were not deleted in the meantime (as a matter of fact, after that last run there were two rows instead of one for each uid value -- there is no uniqueness constraint on that uid column, but I verified in previous backups that there was only one row for each uid).

So I suspect there is a bug in the stack somewhere between Django and the bare metal, but I have no idea where. This is the setting:

Django 1.5.1
Python 2.7.3
Database: MySQL 5.5 (5.5.22-0ubuntu1)
OS: Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (x86) running in a KVM virtual machine.
The physical server itself is probably irrelevant, as the problem has occurred with the VM on two different servers (one Intel Xeon and one Core i5).

Has somebody experienced something similar? And found a solution?

Comment: Can you not replicate this with a test?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. It happens randomly, and very seldom (3 or 4 detected times in 3 years).